# Convert columns into rows with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So my dataset has some information by location for n dates. The problem is each date is actually a different column header. For example the CSV looks like

```
location    name    Jan-2010    Feb-2010    March-2010
A           "test"  12          20          30
B           "foo"   18          20          25
```

What I would like is for it to look like

```
location    name    Date        Value
A           "test"  Jan-2010    12       
A           "test"  Feb-2010    20
A           "test"  March-2010  30
B           "foo"   Jan-2010    18       
B           "foo"   Feb-2010    20
B           "foo"   March-2010  25
```

My problem is I don't know how many dates are in the column (though I know they will always start after name)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842066/python-pandas-certain-columns-to-rows

Answer (score 413, accepted):

**UPDATE**
From v0.20, [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) is a first order function, you can now use

```
df.melt(id_vars=["location", "name"], 
        var_name="Date", 
        value_name="Value")

  location    name        Date  Value
0        A  "test"    Jan-2010     12
1        B   "foo"    Jan-2010     18
2        A  "test"    Feb-2010     20
3        B   "foo"    Feb-2010     20
4        A  "test"  March-2010     30
5        B   "foo"  March-2010     25
```

---

**OLD(ER) VERSIONS: <0.20**

You can use [`pd.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) to get most of the way there, and then sort:

```
>>> df
  location  name  Jan-2010  Feb-2010  March-2010
0        A  test        12        20          30
1        B   foo        18        20          25
>>> df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["location", "name"], 
                  var_name="Date", value_name="Value")
>>> df2
  location  name        Date  Value
0        A  test    Jan-2010     12
1        B   foo    Jan-2010     18
2        A  test    Feb-2010     20
3        B   foo    Feb-2010     20
4        A  test  March-2010     30
5        B   foo  March-2010     25
>>> df2 = df2.sort(["location", "name"])
>>> df2
  location  name        Date  Value
0        A  test    Jan-2010     12
2        A  test    Feb-2010     20
4        A  test  March-2010     30
1        B   foo    Jan-2010     18
3        B   foo    Feb-2010     20
5        B   foo  March-2010     25
```

(Might want to throw in a `.reset_index(drop=True)`, just to keep the output clean.)

**Note**: `pd.DataFrame.sort` [has been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123874/dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-sort) in favour of [`pd.DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

Comment: @DSM what would be the inverse of this function. i.e. how would one convert `df2` [back] to `df`

Comment: @3kstc Try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28337117/2336725) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152691/2336725).  You're wanting to look into pivots.  Possibly `pandas.pivot_table(df2,values='Value',index=['location','name'],columns='Date').reset_index()`.

Comment: @DSM is there any way to go backwards? Meaning that I have a lot of rows with the same name and I would want all the dates to be on different columns

Comment: @Adrian you can unmelt / reverse melt (a.k.a pivoting) on df operations. For more details check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337117/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe-in-pandas

Answer (score 30):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `MultiIndex Series`, then for `DataFrame` add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `rename`:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(["location", "name"])
         .stack()
         .reset_index(name='Value')
         .rename(columns={'level_2':'Date'}))
print (df1)
  location  name        Date  Value
0        A  test    Jan-2010     12
1        A  test    Feb-2010     20
2        A  test  March-2010     30
3        B   foo    Jan-2010     18
4        B   foo    Feb-2010     20
5        B   foo  March-2010     25
```

Answer (score 10):

#### [`pd.wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

You can add a prefix to your year columns and then feed directly to `pd.wide_to_long`. I won't pretend this is *efficient*, but it may in certain situations be more convenient than [`pd.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html), e.g. when your columns already have an appropriate prefix.

```
df.columns = np.hstack((df.columns[:2], df.columns[2:].map(lambda x: f'Value{x}')))

res = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['Value'], i='name', j='Date').reset_index()\
        .sort_values(['location', 'name'])

print(res)

   name        Date location  Value
0  test    Jan-2010        A     12
2  test    Feb-2010        A     20
4  test  March-2010        A     30
1   foo    Jan-2010        B     18
3   foo    Feb-2010        B     20
5   foo  March-2010        B     25
```

Comment: I know this is few years old now, but while learning the differences on how to use `pd.stack()` `pd.melt()` and `pd.wide_to_long()` i came across to this answer, tested it myself and it just didn't want to get me the same result (I just got an empty df for `res`). In the end I figured out I need to add `suffix=r".+"` to come to the same result. Was it different back then or did it never worked but nobody noticed or cared? Or did I miss something ? It is not that I want to correct here, I just want to be sure I understand what is going on with these commands.

Comment: @Rabinzel, I'm not sure what has changed in the functionality. But what I can say is that I tested the code and it worked at the time I wrote this answer. It would be interesting, if it's true, to know why the suffix parameter is required.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Just wanted to verify if the problem is on my side or I am missunderstanding something. After googling a bit, I read several times that `wide_to_long` expects numerical suffix or it will fail but in the documentation all it says is that `suffix="\d+"` is the default.

Answer (score 9):

I guess I found a simpler solution

```
temp1 = pd.melt(df1, id_vars=["location"], var_name='Date', value_name='Value')
temp2 = pd.melt(df1, id_vars=["name"], var_name='Date', value_name='Value')
```

Concat whole `temp1` with `temp2`'s column `name`

```
temp1['new_column'] = temp2['name']
```

You now have what you asked for.

Answer (score 6):

Adding a link to a notebook which you can duplicate, demonstrating @DMS's answer using [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
df.melt(id_vars=["location", "name"], 
    var_name="date", 
    value_name="value")
```

https://deepnote.com/@DataScience/Unpivot-a-DataFrame-from-wide-to-long-format-lN7WlqOdSlqroI_7DGAkoA

Answer (score 5):

If you want to swap your rows with columns & columns with rows then try the **transpose** method of pandas:

```
df.T
```

Check the reference link:
https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pandas-t-transpose/