# DataFrame: add same data for different column and merge the whole file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame which looks like this:

```
Name Year Jan Feb Mar Apr
Bee  1998 26  23  22  19
Cee  1999 43  23  43  23
```

I want to change the DataFrame into something like this:

```
Name Year Mon Val
Bee  1998 1   26
Bee  1998 2   23
Bee  1998 3   22
Bee  1998 4   19
Cee  1999 1   43
Cee  1999 2   23
Cee  1999 3   43
Cee  1999 4   23
```

How do i acquire this in Python with Pandas or any other library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas convert some columns into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/pandas-convert-some-columns-into-rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, reshape your DataFrame with `pd.DataFrame.melt`:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['Name', 'Year'], var_name='Mon', value_name='Value')
```

...and then convert your `Mon` values to datetime values, and extract the month number:

```
df.loc[:, 'Mon'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Mon'], format='%b').dt.month

#   Name  Year  Mon  Value
# 0  Bee  1998    1     26
# 1  Cee  1999    1     43
# 2  Bee  1998    2     23
# 3  Cee  1999    2     23
# 4  Bee  1998    3     22
# 5  Cee  1999    3     43
# 6  Bee  1998    4     19
# 7  Cee  1999    4     23
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.set_index(['Name', 'Year'])
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%b').month
df.stack()
```

returns

```
Name  Year   
Bee   1998  1    26
            2    23
            3    22
            4    19
Cee   1999  1    43
            2    23
            3    43
            4    23
dtype: int64
```