# Change dataframe values automatically

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table.

```
Row_count EXP1 EXP2
2544       24   22
```

I want it like this:

```
Row_count EXP TOTAL_I.V
2544      EXP1   24
2544      EXP2   22
```

Comment: I think you want `stack().reset_index()`

Comment: use melt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/pandas-convert-some-columns-into-rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["Row_count"], 
              var_name="Exp", value_name="TOTAL_I.V")
```