# Selectively converting columns to rows

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to transpose the following data in such a way that time is left as the index column and col A to col D are returned as rows in col B while the values under col A to col D become their own column

To give you a visual example. This is an example of what I currently have

```
time colA colB colC colD colE colF colG
12     1    4   5     9    4   3    3
13     2    7   6     8    3   4    5
```

This is my desired output:

```
time  cols   vals
 12   colA    1
 12   colB    4
 12   colC    5
 12   colD    9 
 12   colE    4
 12   colF    3
 12   colG    3 
 13   colA    2
 13   colB    7
 13   colC    6
 13   colD    8
  etc.....
```

What I have tried. I tried literally transposing the data frame, but obviously changes columns to rows, which is only half correct

```
df = df.transpose()
```

I gave it a bit more thought and currently researching using the pivot table function for this, but I am not sure if this even makes sense

I don't think this is a duplicate of 
[pandas convert some columns into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/pandas-convert-some-columns-into-rows)

Trying this

```
df.melt(id_vars='time_period',var_name='cols',value_name='value')
```

Returns the time as one column, the second column as all the unique values from the second column

Comment: This is either `stack` or `melt`, or `wide_to_long`.

Comment: `df.melt('time',var_name='cols')`

Comment: @anky_91 that doesn't seem to produce the desired output

Comment: @Emm do you mean the order? value wise it does according to the question: `df.set_index('time').stack().reset_index(name='vals').rename(columns={'level_1':'cols'})`

Comment: After melting, you can use `ddf.sort_values('time').reset_index(drop=True)` to sort on `time` column.