# Create table from row

Tags: python, pandas

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/pandas-convert-some-columns-into-rows), I've been trying to use `melt` but without success..

I've got a DataFrame with 1 row, like this:

```py
   A   B   C   total   date   A_size   B_size   C_size   total_size
0  4   2   5    11 2019-01-01  123      456      789        1368
```

Which I'd like to turn into this (at this point I don't care about `date` anymore):

```py
      Values     Sizes
A        4        123
B        2        456
C        5        789
total    11       1368
```

I've got something terribly hacky that does the job, but it's not flexible. I'd like to be able to add `D` and `D_size` without having to modify the downstream code.

Hacky code:

```py
def format_table(todays_metadata: pd.DataFrame):
    todays_metadata_reformat = todays_metadata.loc[:, 'A':'total'] # hardcoded 'A'
    todays_metadata_reformat.index = ['Values']
    sizes = todays_metadata.loc[:, 'A_size':'total_size'] # hardcoded 'A_size'
    sizes.index = ['Sizes']
    sizes.columns = todays_metadata_reformat.columns
    todays_metadata_reformat = 
    todays_metadata_reformat.append(sizes).transpose()
    return todays_metadata_reformat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the index for position of the `total` column by [`pd.Index.get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) and create slices:

```
df1=df.drop('date',1)
i=df1.columns[:df1.columns.get_loc('total')+1] # ['A', 'B', 'C', 'total']
j=df1.columns[df1.columns.get_loc('total')+1:] #['A_size','B_size','C_size','total_size']
```

---

Then melt and concat:

```
m=df1[j].melt(value_name='size')
m.index=m.pop('variable').str.split('_').str[0]
pd.concat([df1[i].melt().set_index('variable'),m],axis=1)
```

---

EDIT:

another way using [`df.filter()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=df+filter&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=df+filter&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1510j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

```
df1=df.drop('date',1)
m=df.filter(like='size')
```

---

```
x=df1[df1.columns.difference(m.columns,sort=False)].melt().set_index('variable')
y=m.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[0]).melt(value_name='Sizes').set_index('variable')
print(pd.concat([x,y],axis=1))
```

---

```
           value  Sizes
variable              
A             4    123
B             2    456
C             5    789
total        11   1368
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it more robust, i.e. not rely on ordering of the columns?
I'd like it to be flexible enough that anything appended with `_size` it can link to the Values of that object, if at all possible

Comment: @Guus added another way, please check if it scales for you

Comment: that's great, thanks! I had to replace the `x.split('_')` with `x.replace('_size', '')` as my actual values could contain underscores as well. But that's a beautifully flexible solution