# Expand pandas dataframe from columns to rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
| ID    | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name4|
|id001  | Jesse | Mary  | Jones | None |
|id002  | Phil  | None  | None  | None |
|id003  | Liam  | Ben   | Rose  | Kate |
|id004  | Chris | David | Diana | None |
```

and I want it to look like:

```
| ID    | Name  |
|id001  | Jesse |
|id001  | Mary  |
|id001  | Jones |
|id002  | Phil  |
|id003  | Liam  |
|id003  | Ben   |
|id003  | Rose  |
|id003  | Kate  |
|id004  | Chris |
|id004  | David |
|id004  | Diana |
```

I've seen a few questions were they want to do something similar but starting just from one column such as [Jess, Mary, Jones]. Any way I can do that?

Comment: Check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54783415/2901002) - `df1 = (df.set_index(["ID"])
         .stack()
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .reset_index(name='Name'))`

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly the same question. I don't have all the names in one column as opposed to that question.

Comment: Not understand, solution from comment not working?