# How to convert many columns into rows in python dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, transpose

I have a data frame with the following structure. I need to bring all the values in columns `code1`,`code2`,`code3`into different rows under same `name`. Similarly for `text`columns.

```
Name      Code1   text1  code2  text2  code3  text3     
Alexa     362     Eng    639    scien  563    maths
john      23      cri    36     ball   03     value
```

What I would like is for it to look like

```
Name      Code   text 
Alexa     362    Eng    
Alexa     639    scien  
Alexa     563    maths
john      23     cri    
john      36     ball   
john      03     value
```

Comment: you can check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/pandas-convert-some-columns-into-rows

Comment: Is only solving half the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each name, you can add a new row with their code and text in a separate dataframe.

```
r, c = df.shape  # original dataframe shape
df2 = pd.DataFrame()  # Create a new dataframe
for i in range(r):
    name = df.iloc[i, 0]
    for j in range(1, c, 2):
        df2 = df2.append({'Name': name, 'Code': df.iloc[i, j], 'Text': df.iloc[i, j + 1]},ignore_index=True)
print(df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with `df` as below (note all headers in lowercase for consistency):

```
#    name  code1 text1  code2  text2  code3  text3
#0  Alexa    362   Eng    639  scien    563  maths
#1   john     23   cri     36   ball      3  value
```

**Execute the following:**

```
df1=pd.melt(df, id_vars=["name"], value_vars=df[['code1','code2','code3']], var_name='initial code column', value_name="code")
df1=df1.drop(columns=['initial code column'])

df2=pd.melt(df, id_vars=["name"], value_vars=df[['text1','text2','text3']], var_name='initial text column', value_name="text")
df2=df2.drop(columns=['initial text column'])    #you don't need this either

diff= df2[df2.columns.difference(df1.columns)]
df=pd.concat([df1,diff],axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
#    name  code   text
#0  Alexa   362    Eng
#1   john    23    cri
#2  Alexa   639  scien
#3   john    36   ball
#4  Alexa   563  maths
#5   john     3  value
```

**Comments:**

- create `df1` with `pd.melt` to get all codes under one column,
  respectively `df2` for text values
- `var_name`("initial code column") is something that `pd.melt`
  creates, useful sometimes, but not in your case, so drop this column; same
  with "initial text column"
- use `difference` and `concat` to build the required `df`