# Python Pandas: Convert columns to rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Dataframe:

```
ORD_DATE   Weekday   ALL Sales       ALL Pred          Other Sales   Other Pred  
1/1/2020   2        48386.27        20815269.83        15386.27       5643158.509
```

I would have approx. 1000 different Sale/Pred combos. I want it this way:

```
ORD_DATE  Weekday   Sales            Pred          Filter  
1/1/2020   2        48386.27        20815269.83    All  
1/1/2020   2        15386.27        5643158.509    Other
```

I have tried Transpose but did not get the results I wanted.

Comment: Try to create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Have you look into this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/pandas-convert-some-columns-into-rows ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas convert some columns into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/pandas-convert-some-columns-into-rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, first move all unaltered columns into the index, then split the remaining column names and create a MultiIndex out of their components, and finally `stack` one of the column levels.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [
        {
            "ORD_DATE": "1/1/2020",
            "Weekday": 2,
            "ALL_Sales": 48386.27,
            "ALL_Pred": 20815269.83,
            "Other_Sales": 15386.27,
            "Other_Pred": 5643158.509,
        }
    ]
)

df = df.set_index(["ORD_DATE", "Weekday"])
split_cols = [c.split("_") for c in df.columns]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(split_cols, names=["Filter", None])
df = df.stack("Filter").reset_index()
print(df)

   ORD_DATE  Weekday Filter          Pred     Sales
0  1/1/2020        2    ALL  2.081527e+07  48386.27
1  1/1/2020        2  Other  5.643159e+06  15386.27
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas.concat with slicing to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ORD_DATE':['1/1/2020'],
    'Weekday':[2],
    'ALL Sales':[48386.27],
    'ALL Pred':[20815269.83],
    'Other Sales':[15386.27],
    'Other Pred':[5643158.509],
})

df2 = pd.concat([
    df[['ORD_DATE','Weekday','ALL Sales','ALL Pred']].rename(columns={
        'ALL Sales':'Sales',
        'ALL Pred':'Pred',
    }),
    df[['ORD_DATE','Weekday','Other Sales','Other Pred']].rename(columns={
        'Other Sales':'Sales',
        'Other Pred':'Pred',
    }),
])

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   ORD_DATE  Weekday     Sales          Pred
0  1/1/2020        2  48386.27  2.081527e+07
0  1/1/2020        2  15386.27  5.643159e+06
```

[Example in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20'ORD_DATE'%3A%5B'1/1/2020'%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20'Weekday'%3A%5B2%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20'ALL%20Sales'%3A%5B48386.27%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20'ALL%20Pred'%3A%5B20815269.83%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20'Other%20Sales'%3A%5B15386.27%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20'Other%20Pred'%3A%5B5643158.509%5D,%0A%7D%29%0A%0Adf2%20%3D%20pd.concat%28%5B%0A%20%20%20%20df%5B%5B'ORD_DATE','Weekday','ALL%20Sales','ALL%20Pred'%5D%5D.rename%28columns%3D%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'ALL%20Sales'%3A'Sales',%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'ALL%20Pred'%3A'Pred',%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%29,%0A%20%20%20%20df%5B%5B'ORD_DATE','Weekday','Other%20Sales','Other%20Pred'%5D%5D.rename%28columns%3D%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Other%20Sales'%3A'Sales',%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Other%20Pred'%3A'Pred',%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%29,%0A%5D%29%0Aprint%28df2%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=8&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Edit With the Filter Column added:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ORD_DATE':['1/1/2020'],
    'Weekday':[2],
    'ALL Sales':[48386.27],
    'ALL Pred':[20815269.83],
    'Other Sales':[15386.27],
    'Other Pred':[5643158.509],
})

df_all = df[['ORD_DATE','Weekday','ALL Sales','ALL Pred']].rename(columns={
        'ALL Sales':'Sales',
        'ALL Pred':'Pred',
})
df_all['Filter'] = 'All'
df_other = df[['ORD_DATE','Weekday','Other Sales','Other Pred']].rename(columns={
        'Other Sales':'Sales',
        'Other Pred':'Pred',
})
df_other['Filter'] = 'Other'

df2 = pd.concat([df_all,df_other,])

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   ORD_DATE  Weekday     Sales          Pred Filter
0  1/1/2020        2  48386.27  2.081527e+07    All
0  1/1/2020        2  15386.27  5.643159e+06  Other
```

[python tutor link](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20'ORD_DATE'%3A%5B'1/1/2020'%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20'Weekday'%3A%5B2%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20'ALL%20Sales'%3A%5B48386.27%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20'ALL%20Pred'%3A%5B20815269.83%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20'Other%20Sales'%3A%5B15386.27%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20'Other%20Pred'%3A%5B5643158.509%5D,%0A%7D%29%0A%0Adf_all%20%3D%20df%5B%5B'ORD_DATE','Weekday','ALL%20Sales','ALL%20Pred'%5D%5D.rename%28columns%3D%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'ALL%20Sales'%3A'Sales',%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'ALL%20Pred'%3A'Pred',%0A%7D%29%0Adf_all%5B'Filter'%5D%20%3D%20'All'%0Adf_other%20%3D%20df%5B%5B'ORD_DATE','Weekday','Other%20Sales','Other%20Pred'%5D%5D.rename%28columns%3D%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Other%20Sales'%3A'Sales',%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Other%20Pred'%3A'Pred',%0A%7D%29%0Adf_other%5B'Filter'%5D%20%3D%20'Other'%0A%0Adf2%20%3D%20pd.concat%28%5Bdf_all,df_other,%5D%29%0Aprint%28df2%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=8&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the positions of ALL and Other in the column names, and then reshape the dataframe using pandas' [wide to long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) method.

```
#reshape column position
#allows manipulation with pd wide to long
df.columns = [' '.join(reversed(ent.split()))
              if ('ALL' in ent) or ('Other' in ent) else ent 
              for ent in df.columns ]

df

    ORD_DATE    Weekday Sales ALL   Pred ALL    Sales Other Pred Other
0   1/1/2020    2   48386.27    20815269.83 15386.27    5643158.509

#reshape data using pandas wide to long
res = (pd.wide_to_long(df,
                       stubnames = ['Sales','Pred'],
                       i = ['ORD_DATE','Weekday'],
                       j = 'Filter',
                       sep = ' ',
                       suffix = '[a-zA-Z]+'
                      )
       .reset_index()
      )

res

    ORD_DATE    Weekday Filter   Sales        Pred
0   1/1/2020       2     ALL    48386.27    2.081527e+07
1   1/1/2020       2    Other   15386.27    5.643159e+06
```

Another route, inspired by @BallPointPen's solution :

```
#set first two columns as index
df = df.set_index(['ORD_DATE','Weekday'])

#split column on whitespace
#using the str partition creates a multiindex 
#drop the 1st level, since it contains the whitespace, and is not needed
#assign back to columns
df.columns = df.columns.str.partition(' ').droplevel(1)

#stack the dataframe
res = df.stack(0).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_2':'Filter'})
res

    ORD_DATE    Weekday Filter     Pred         Sales
0   1/1/2020    2       ALL     2.081527e+07    48386.27
1   1/1/2020    2       Other   5.643159e+06    15386.27
```