# How to special transpose in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
Category 3,Chapter I,Chapter II,Chapter III
prima,126,97,83
da,38,24,24
sps.,22,17,18
```

How to make it like:

```
prima,126,Chapter I
prima, 97, Chapter II
prima, 83, Chapter III
da, 38, Chapter I
[...]
```

Comment: `df.melt('Category 3')`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas convert some columns into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/pandas-convert-some-columns-into-rows)

Comment: df.stack() would basically do the job, as it stack a level from the columns as the inner most labels in the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can run:

```
result = df.set_index('Category 3').stack().rename('Value').reset_index()
```

For your data sample the result is:

```
  Category 3      level_1  Value
0      prima    Chapter I    126
1      prima   Chapter II     97
2      prima  Chapter III     83
3         da    Chapter I     38
4         da   Chapter II     24
5         da  Chapter III     24
6       sps.    Chapter I     22
7       sps.   Chapter II     17
8       sps.  Chapter III     18
```

If you want, rename *level_1* column to any meaningful name
and change the order of columns.