# Is there a way to sum 2 columns by grouping 2 other columns on the same value?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using a data frame like this:

```
home_team away_team  home_score  away_score 
Scotland   England           0           0   
England   Scotland           4           2   
Scotland   England           2           1   
England   Scotland           2           2   
Scotland   England           3           0
```

Here's what I would like to accomplish, I'm trying to regroup all the country together whether they are home or away and have the sum total of the score.

```
Team    total goal
Scotland   9
England    7
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas convert some columns into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/pandas-convert-some-columns-into-rows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this and let me know if you face any issue/error. Here you go:

```
df.groupby("home_team").home_score.sum()+df.groupby("away_team").away_score.sum()
```

Comment: it's working my boi! Can you explain to me the logic behind ? I'm not sure what the .home_score is doing after the groupby.

Comment: Break it down into steps to understand 
`df2 = df.groupby('home_team')['home_score'].sum()`
`df3 = df.groupby('away_team')['away_score'].sum()`
`df4 = df2 + df3`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (assuming your original DataFrame is called df):

```
nations = ["England", "Scotland"]
tot = pd.DataFrame([(nation, 0) for nation in nations], columns=["team","total goal"])

for nation in nations:
    home_goal = sum(df[df["home_team"] == nation]["home_score"])
    away_goal = sum(df[df["away_team"] == nation]["away_score"]) 
    tot.loc[tot.team == nation, "total goal"] = home_goal + away_goal
```