# how to splits columns by date using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

```
df.head(7)
df

Month,ward1,ward2,...ward30
    Apr-19, 20, 30,   45
    May-19, 18, 25,   42
    Jun-19, 25, 19,   35
    Jul-19, 28, 22,   38
    Aug-19, 24, 15,   40
    Sep-19, 21, 14,   39
    Oct-19, 15, 18,   41
```

to:

```
Month, ward1
Apr-19, 20  
May-19, 18  
Jun-19, 25  
Jul-19, 28  
Aug-19, 24  
Sep-19, 21  
Oct-19, 15  

Month,ward2 
Apr-19, 30  
May-19, 25  
Jun-19, 19  
Jul-19, 22  
Aug-19, 15  
Sep-19, 14  
Oct-19, 18  

Month, ward30
Apr-19, 45
May-19, 42
Jun-19, 35
Jul-19, 38
Aug-19, 40
Sep-19, 39
Oct-19, 41
```

How to group-by date wise in python using pandas?

I have dataframe df that contains a datetime and 30 other columns which I want to split by date attached with each of those columns in pandas but I am facing some difficulties.

Comment: Do you need https://stackoverflow.com/q/28654047 ?

Comment: @jezrael No, I don't think he needs `melt`. I think he wants to split the df into multiple dfs like mentioned in the question.

Comment: @MayankPorwal - yop, it was reason not close ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using a dictionary comprehension to hold your separate dataframes.

```
dfs = {col : df.set_index('Month')[[col]] for col in (df.set_index('Month').columns)}

print(dfs['ward1'])

        ward1
Month        
Apr-19     20
May-19     18
Jun-19     25
Jul-19     28
Aug-19     24
Sep-19     21
Oct-19     15

print(dfs['ward30'])

        ward30
Month         
Apr-19      45
May-19      42
Jun-19      35
Jul-19      38
Aug-19      40
Sep-19      39
Oct-19      41
```

Comment: @BHAVESHSADHU don't forget to accept this answer if it solved your solution so this can be closed. best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

One straight forward way would be to set date column as index and separating out every other column:

```
data.set_index('Month', inplace =True)
data_dict = {col: data[col] for col in data.columns}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to create new DataFrames:

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame()
data1['Month'] = df['Month']
data1['ward1'] = df['ward1']
data1.head()
```