# Python pandas convert column index to value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This seems rather obvious, but I can't seem to figure out how to convert column index of data frame to value?

For example:

From:

[image]

To:

[image]

Comment: You'll have to be more specific, i don't understand what you want to do. Also, please post code to show us what you've tried.

Comment: Use `df = df.stack().rename_axis([None, 'Y']).rename('W').reset_index(level=1)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/pandas-convert-some-columns-into-rows  This answer is just what I want. use df.melt(). Thank you too!