# change matrix shape dataframe to tabular dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe, combinations, data-wrangling

I need to change below dataframe:

[image: input]

I want the output in below form:

[image: OUTPUT]

I tried to use itertools.combinations_with_replacement to get all combination

from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
comb = list(combinations_with_replacement(pairwise_similarity_df.index,2))

matrix is 10000*10000 so i expected 100000000 rows but got only 50005000.

how can i convert this to required format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas convert some columns into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/pandas-convert-some-columns-into-rows)

Comment: @gionni  yes after some modifications it worked..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Gionni,

Below code worked for me:

df['company1']=df.index

df=df.melt(id_vars["company1"],var_name="company2")

[image]