# i want to sort an csv file using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I wanted to convert a csv file using python to be in a different order which I wanted,pls assisit me to do this thankyou!!!

this is the source file
[source csv image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGNuc.png)

and I want it to be converted like this
[required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAlRq.png)

Thank you for helping

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/pandas-convert-some-columns-into-rows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas convert some columns into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/pandas-convert-some-columns-into-rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is probably [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html). But unless you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) there is no way to help you further than that