# Pandas [How to append all columns of a csv file into one]

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have this problem with Pandas as from a 'csv' file with multiple columns I would like to generate a new 'csv' file with a single column containing all the values as in the example below:

From:

column 1, column 2, column 3

1,    2,    3,

4,    5,    6

I would like to obtain:

column 1

1

2

3

4

5

6

Thank you all in advance

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/pandas-convert-some-columns-into-rows , `df.melt().loc[:,['value']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ravel` on DataFrame `values`:

```
pd.DataFrame({'column': df.values.ravel()})
```

Output:

```
   column
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5
5       6
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"column1": [1, 4], "column2": [2, 5], "column3": [3, 6]})
print("df : \n", df)

reshaped_value = df.values.reshape(-1)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["column1"])

new_df["column1"] = reshaped_value
print("\nnew_df : \n", new_df)
```

output :

```
df : 
    column1  column2  column3
0        1        2        3
1        4        5        6

new_df : 
    column1
0        1
1        2
2        3
3        4
4        5
5        6
```

Comment: I thank you very much as well. I tried this method as well and it worked. Thanks again