# Pandas: how to transpose part of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
   A  B   C param1 param2 param3
0  1  4 NaN   val1   val4   val7
1  2  5 NaN   val2   val5   val8
2  3  6 NaN   val3   val6   val9
```

Which I'd like to modify to get:

```
   A  B       C Values
0  1  4  param1   val1
1  1  4  param2   val4
2  1  4  param3   val7
3  2  5  param1   val2
4  2  5  param2   val5
5  2  5  param3   val8
6  3  6  param1   val3
7  3  6  param2   val6
8  3  6  param3   val9
```

How do I achieve this ?

Comment: `df.drop('C', axis=1).melt(id_vars=['A', 'B'], var_name='C', value_name='Values')`

Comment: `df.drop('C', axis=1).set_index(['A', 'B']).stack().reset_index(name='Values').rename(columns={'level_2': 'C'})`

Comment: FWIW I think [pandas convert some columns into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28654047/15497888) would be a much more useful duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.melt(id_vars = ['A','B'], value_vars = ['param1','param2', 'param3'])
```

You can check melt function and it can change the label for the id_vars and value_vars.