# pd.groupby: How to groupby columns within same group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm working with a music database and I have all the data transformed the way I want it to except I cannot yet figure out how to add another level of indexing to my dataframe. So far, I've grouped everything on genre and aggregated a few computations and that came out fine:

[image: current dataframe]

Now I'd like for my dataframe to look like this dataframe where the `major_category` is `genre`, the `minor_category` is all the columns except `duration`, and the values are the ones associated to the respective `minor_category`:

[image: desired dataframe]

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: look at `pd.melt`, set `ignore_index=False`. Also, it is better to share a small reproducible sample of your data, than pics

Comment: There is a good example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/pandas-convert-some-columns-into-rows

Comment: It's just a guess because I don't have a frame work with but something like: `df.set_index('duration', append=True).stack()`

Comment: Nicely represented, but as @sammywemmy says, you should copy paste the raw data and desired output as text. Why? (a) it's easier to read; (b) people wanting to help you can copy paste the text into their code and verify that their advice works.

Comment: Sorry I could have included more code - the data is privately accessed so I was hesitant to share. Basically, I grouped on `genre` and `pd.agg()`'d on the columns I wanted leaving me this.