# converting columns into rows in pd. dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dataframe

How can I convert columns to rows in a pd.dataframe, currently my code is as below in, instead of having my values returned in columns I want them to be displayed in rows, I have tried using iterrows:

```
            df = pd.DataFrame (columns = cleaned_array)
            output = df.to_csv ( index=False, mode='a', encoding = "utf-8")
            print(output)
```

Comment: Transpose your dataframe: `df.T`? or Stack: `df.stack()`?

Comment: You can use this link, it may helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/pandas-convert-some-columns-into-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame (columns = cleaned_array)

df.T
```

This will interchange your rows and columns

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [tranpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) function.

`df.T` or `df.transpose()`