# Pivot a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot

I am new to python. I have a dataframe in below format

[image]

I want to pivot it to below format

[image]

How can i do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas convert some columns into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/pandas-convert-some-columns-into-rows)

Comment: What you are showing is not *Pivot*, its called **melt**  in pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `df.melt`:

```
print(df.melt(id_vars='Name'))
```

If pandas version is under 0.20.0, try `pd.melt`:

```
print(pd.melt(df, id_vars='Name'))
```

Comment: Yes i will in 5 minutes