# Unpivot a pandas groupby dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset of weekly sales of a few stores, which looks something similar to :

| store_id | item_id | week | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| store1 | item1 | 2021-01 | 3 |
| store1 | item2 | 2021-01 | 2 |
| store2 | item1 | 2021-01 | 10 |
| store2 | item3 | 2021-01 | 1 |
| store1 | item1 | 2021-02 | 5 |
| store1 | item2 | 2021-02 | 1 |
| store2 | item1 | 2021-02 | 11 |
| store1 | item3 | 2021-03 | 6 |
| store1 | item1 | 2021-04 | 7 |
| store2 | item3 | 2021-04 | 2 |

I did a pivot on this data frame like :
`df.groupby(['store_id', 'item_id', 'week'])['sales'].mean().unstack()` which generates a new dataframe like the one below :

| store_id | item_id | 2021-01 | 2021-02 | 2021-03 | 2021-04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| store1 | item1 | 3 | 5 | 0 | 7 |
| store1 | item2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| store1 | item3 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| store2 | item1 | 10 | 11 | 0 | 0 |
| store2 | item3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

I have performed the needed modifications to this new dataframe.
**How do we get back the original dataframe structure from this modified pivot dataframe.** such that I can represent each week number as a separate row rather than columns as in this dataframe.

**Edit** :
I tried using melt as an example from [Convert columns into rows with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/convert-columns-into-rows-with-pandas):

```
df.melt(id_vars=["store_id", "item_id"], 
        var_name="week", 
        value_name="sales")
```

But I get the error :
`The following 'id_vars' are not present in the DataFrame: ['store_id', 'item_id']`. This seems probably because my df has multi-indices and not in serialised form.

Output of df.index

```
MultiIndex([('store1', 'item1'),
            ('store1', 'item2'),
           ....
           ....
           names=['store_id', 'item_id'], length=15305)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt). Using the below dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'store_id' : ['store1', 'store1', 'store1', 'store2', 'store2'],
                  'item_id' : ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item1', 'item3'],
                  '2021-01' : [3, 2, 0, 10, 1],
                  '2021-02' : [5, 1, 0, 11, 0],
                  '2021-03' : [0, 0, 6, 0, 0],
                  '2021-04' : [7, 0, 0, 0, 2]})

  store_id item_id  2021-01  2021-02  2021-03  2021-04
0   store1   item1        3        5        0        7
1   store1   item2        2        1        0        0
2   store1   item3        0        0        6        0
3   store2   item1       10       11        0        0
4   store2   item3        1        0        0        2
```

You can then melt, using store and item id as id_vars, and values are the date columns:

```
df.melt(id_vars=['store_id', 'item_id'], var_name='week', value_name='sales')
```

This will give the below:

```
   store_id item_id     week  sales
0    store1   item1  2021-01      3
1    store1   item2  2021-01      2
2    store1   item3  2021-01      0
3    store2   item1  2021-01     10
4    store2   item3  2021-01      1
5    store1   item1  2021-02      5
6    store1   item2  2021-02      1
7    store1   item3  2021-02      0
8    store2   item1  2021-02     11
9    store2   item3  2021-02      0
10   store1   item1  2021-03      0
11   store1   item2  2021-03      0
12   store1   item3  2021-03      6
13   store2   item1  2021-03      0
14   store2   item3  2021-03      0
15   store1   item1  2021-04      7
16   store1   item2  2021-04      0
17   store1   item3  2021-04      0
18   store2   item1  2021-04      0
19   store2   item3  2021-04      2
```

Comment: You can also change directly columns name inside the `melt` function with the parameter `var_name` and `value_name`.

Comment: @AntoineDubuis so you can, have edited

Comment: `value_vars` should be removed.

Comment: @EmiOB
Added an Edit to the question explaining why this is not working.

Comment: @ManishTripathi reset index before melt (`df.reset_index.melt(...)`)