# Create multiple rows from several column indexes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

Please can you help me? This is the structure of my origin dataset:

| Country | 2020 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ecuador | Value1 | Value2 |
| Canada | Value1 | Value2 |

And i would like to get this structure, so the year is a index itself and not multiple columns:

| Country | Year | Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ecuador | 2020 | Value1 |
| Ecuador | 2021 | Value2 |
| Canada | 2020 | Value1 |
| Canada | 2021 | Value2 |

Thank you very much!

Comment: [df.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/convert-columns-into-rows-with-pandas). You can use the [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) method of pandas

```
df.melt(id_vars=['Country'], var_name='Year', value_name='Index')
```

the output is:

```
      Country  Year  Index
   0  Ecuador  2020  Value1
   1   Canada  2020  Value1
   2  Ecuador  2021  Value2
   3   Canada  2021  Value2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Easier than I thought..