# Converting Multi-level columns to single level in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi level columns:

| Item | CBP |  | SAC |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Qty | Date | Qty | Date |
| Item A | 20 | 2/10/2021 | 32 | 3/12/2022 |

How do use pandas to change the above table to:

| Item | Branch | Qty | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item A | CBP | 20 | 2/10/2021 |
| Item A | SAC | 30 | 3/12/2022 |

I usually use the melt in pandas ([Convert columns into rows with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/convert-columns-into-rows-with-pandas/28654127#28654127))

I dont know how to process this since there is two level. Need help Thank you very much.

Comment: it'll help if you can paste the first dataframe such that we can copy and run it. Use `df.head().to_dict()` and paste the output for that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all are columns:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['Item', 'CBP', 'CBP', 'SAC', 'SAC'], [None, 'Qty', 'Date', 'Qty', 'Date']])
df = pd.DataFrame([['Item A', 20, '2/10/2021', 32, '3/12/2022']],
                  columns=idx)
```

You can set the Item columns aside as index and `stack`. `explode` Items after reshaping to get rid of the extra level.

```
(df.set_index('Item')
   .rename_axis(columns=('Branch',None))
   .stack(0)
   .reset_index()
   .explode('Item')
 )
```

Output:

```
     Item Branch       Date  Qty
0  Item A    CBP  2/10/2021   20
1  Item A    SAC  3/12/2022   32
```