# Concatenating columns of a dataframe with consecutive numbers in column names below each other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a list of files containing data from sensors together with some data to identify where the sensor output comes from. I have a dataframe `df1` that might look like this:

| Product | Date | Sensor 1 data | Sensor 2 data | Sensor 1 cal. | Sensor 2 cal. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | 23-09-2022 | 12 | 25 | 84 | 32 |
| Product 2 | 23-09-2022 | 56 | 28 | 32 | 65 |
| Product 1 | 23-09-2022 | 95 | 65 | 43 | 91 |

I need to combine the data from all sensors in one long dataframe `df_all`, but I need to keep the identification data, so I know where my data comes from. Hence, the final dataframe should look something like this:

| Product | Date | Sensor data | Sensors cal. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | 23-09-2022 | 12 | 84 |
| Product 2 | 23-09-2022 | 56 | 32 |
| Product 1 | 23-09-2022 | 95 | 43 |
| Product 1 | 23-09-2022 | 25 | 32 |
| Product 2 | 23-09-2022 | 28 | 65 |
| Product 1 | 23-09-2022 | 65 | 91 |

My initial approach was to rename the columns in the original dataframe with

```
df1.rename(columns={"Sensor 1 data": "Sensor data", "Sensor 1 cal.": "Sensor cal."})
df_all = pd.concat([df_all, df1['Product','Date','Sensor data', 'Sensor cal.']])

df1.rename(columns={"Sensor 2": "Sensor data", "Sensor 2 cal.": "Sensor cal."})
df_all = pd.concat([df_all, df1['Product','Date','Sensor data', 'Sensor cal.']])
```

But using this approach I would need to re-rename the columns back to their original names as I progress, as I would otherwise end up with columns having the same name.

It should be noted, that the column names can be different in different files as well. So "Sensor 1 data" might be called "Sensor value 1" in a different file.

Comment: Need https://stackoverflow.com/a/53286045/2901002

Comment: What if I have other columns (that i don't know the names of) in the initial dataframe that I don't want to include in the final dataframe?

Comment: First remove it by `drop`

Comment: But that would require that I know the names or indexes of the columns I want to drop, which I don't.