# Combine separate year and month keys to then have all the avg_price data rearranged in accordance to the date. Python, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

My table has the 12 months along the x-axis and the years along the y-axis and the data is the average price for each month. I need the data to be one column of data corresponding to the year/month in datetime format.

[image]

|  | Jan | Feb | Mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1980 | .489 | .445 | .400 |
| 1981 | .523 | .567 | .600 |

I somehow achieved this with the .datetime() function within a tutorial but was not able to recreate it with my next .csv file. I looked at the documentation for .melt .pivot .pivot_table .wide_to_long and did not have success.

| DateTime | Avg_Price |
| --- | --- |
| 1980-Jan | .489 |
| 1980-Feb | .445 |
| 1980-Mar | .400 |
| 1981-Jan | .523 |
| 1981-Feb | .567 |
| 1981-Mar | .600 |

Comment: Do you have any code you are working with? Hard to suggest a path forward with no example attempt

Comment: Pandas has several paths that can lead to this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/convert-columns-into-rows-with-pandas

Comment: you can use melt function, i have posted a code snippet below that might work

Answer (score 0):

Put the data in txt format and use the below code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep = '\t')

df_temp = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Year'], var_name='Month', value_name='Average Price')

df_temp['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_temp['Year'].astype(str) + '-' + df_temp['Month'] + '-01')


df_final = df_temp.drop(['Year', 'Month'], axis=1)

print(df_final)
```