# How can I transform data in Pandas so my selected column names become row values and rows increase?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I have a large dataset that looks like the one below:

| CUSTOMER ID | Apples | Oranges | Bananas | Pineapple | Other Items |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CUST_123 | Yes | Yes | No | No | No |
| CUST_456 | No | Yes | No | Yes | No |
| CUST_789 | No | No | No | No | Yes |

What I would like to do is, have it in the following format:

| CUSTOMER ID | Item |
| --- | --- |
| CUST_123 | Apples |
| CUST_123 | Oranges |
| CUST_456 | Oranges |
| CUST_456 | Pineapple |
| CUST_789 | Other Item |

Any idea how I may transform it like this? The dataset is quite large think 10,000 records easily and there are at least 10-15 categories laid out like the one in Table 1. I need in the Table 2 format.

I have tried the approach shared here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/convert-columns-into-rows-with-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com) but I don't think I am using melt correctly or it isn't the correct way to get the desired result. I would really appreciate some guidance/advice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

use `melt`

```
out = (df.melt('CUSTOMER ID', var_name='Item')
         .query('value == "Yes"')
         .drop('value', axis=1))
```

out:

```
   CUSTOMER ID         Item
0     CUST_123       Apples
3     CUST_123      Oranges
4     CUST_456      Oranges
10    CUST_456    Pineapple
14    CUST_789  Other Items
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'CUSTOMER ID': ['CUST_123', 'CUST_456', 'CUST_789'], 
         'Apples': ['Yes', 'No', 'No'], 'Oranges': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'No'], 
         'Bananas': ['No', 'No', 'No'], 'Pineapple': ['No', 'Yes', 'No'], 
         'Other Items': ['No', 'No', 'Yes']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with index operations:

```
out = (df.set_index('CUSTOMER ID').rename_axis(columns='Item')
         .stack().loc[lambda x: x == 'Yes']
         .index.to_frame(index=False))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  CUSTOMER ID         Item
0    CUST_123       Apples
1    CUST_123      Oranges
2    CUST_456      Oranges
3    CUST_456    Pineapple
4    CUST_789  Other Items
```