# Pandas dataframe loop all values for certain column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

Working with pandas dataframe suppose i have data frame with similar structure as following:

```
import pandas as pd
a_choise = ["True", "False", "False", "False", "True", "False", "False", "True", "True"]
b_choise = ["True", "True", "False", "False", "False", "False", "True", "True", "True"]
c_choise = ["False", "False", "True", "False", "True", "True", "False", "True", "False"]
a_n = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9"]
b_n = ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5", "b6", "b7", "b8", "b9"]
c_n = ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8", "c9"]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"a": list(range(1, 10)), "b": list(range(11, 20)), "c": range(21, 30), 
     "a_Cho":a_choise, "b_Cho":b_choise, "c_Cho":c_choise,
     "a_n":a_n, "b_n":b_n, "c_n":c_n}
)
    a   b   c   a_Cho   b_Cho   c_Cho   a_n b_n c_n
0   1   11  21  True    True    False   a1  b1  c1
1   2   12  22  False   True    False   a2  b2  c2
2   3   13  23  False   False   True    a3  b3  c3
3   4   14  24  False   False   False   a4  b4  c4
4   5   15  25  True    False   True    a5  b5  c5
5   6   16  26  False   False   True    a6  b6  c6
6   7   17  27  False   True    False   a7  b7  c7
7   8   18  28  True    True    True    a8  b8  c8
8   9   19  29  True    True    False   a9  b9  c9
```

I want a new 2 columns (Choise, Value) that meet the follwoing conditions
for all values in "a_Cho", "b_Cho", And "c_Cho"

- if "a_Cho" = true then choise = "a_n", value = a  for the corresponding value of "a_Cho" elif "a_Cho" = false then move to next
- if "b_Cho" = true then choise = "b_n", value = b for the corresponding value of "b_Cho"elif "b_Cho" = false then move to next
- if "c_Cho" = true then choise = "c_n", value = c for the corresponding value of "c_Cho"elif "c_Cho" = false then move to next
- if "x_Cho" = false then value and choise = "Invalide"

Comment: df_val = []
    df_name = []
cols = ["coln_present", "colm_present", ".... ]
for x in df[cols]:
    if df1['coln_present'][df1['coln_present'] ==True]:
        df_val.append(df1.coln_val)
        df_name.append(df1.p1_coln_name)
    elif df1['colm_present'][df1['colm_present'] ==True]:
        df_val.append(df1.colm_val)
        df_name.append(df1.p1_colm_name)
    else:
        df_val.append("Not_Valid")
        df_name.append("Not_Valid")
    
    
    ##

Comment: There is a sample code I add to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edited

Thank you for updating your question. Following your edit, I believe [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) will be useful to you. `.loc` allows us to perform "logical indexing", grabbing rows based on column equalities.

For example, the following gets all rows where column `a_Cho` is equal to `"True"`,

```
>>> df.loc[df.a_Cho.eq('True'), ['a_n', 'a']]
    a   b   c   a_Cho   b_Cho   c_Cho   a_n b_n c_n
0   1   11  21  True    True    False   a1  b1  c1
4   5   15  25  True    False   True    a5  b5  c5
7   8   18  28  True    True    True    a8  b8  c8
8   9   19  29  True    True    False   a9  b9  c9
```

We can also select a subset of columns using `.loc`.

```
>>> df.loc[df.a_Cho.eq("True"), ["a_n", "a"]].rename(columns={"a_n": "choise", "a": "value"})
```

where I've used [`.rename()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to rename the columns.

Using the above approach, we can perform logical indexing for each of the conditions you state then concatenate the results.

```
def new_col_names(x):
    return {x + "_n": "choise", x: "value"}

# logical criteria
only_a = df.a_Cho.eq("True")
only_b = df.a_Cho.eq("False") & df.b_Cho.eq("True")
only_c = df.a_Cho.eq("False") & df.b_Cho.eq("False") & df.c_Cho.eq("True")
invalid = df.a_Cho.eq("False") & df.b_Cho.eq("False") & df.c_Cho.eq("False")

df_a = df.loc[only_a, ["a_n", "a"]].rename(columns=new_col_names("a"))
df_b = df.loc[only_b, ["b_n", "b"]].rename(columns=new_col_names("b"))
df_c = df.loc[only_c, ["c_n", "c"]].rename(columns=new_col_names("c"))
df_inv = df.loc[invalid].assign(choise="invalide", value="invalide").copy()
df_inv = df_inv[["choise", "value"]]

df_new = pd.concat([df_a, df_b, df_c, df_inv])
```

The final `DataFrame` looks like:

```
    choise    value
0   a1         1
4   a5         5
7   a8         8
8   a9         9
1   b2        12
6   b7        17
2   c3        23
5   c6        26
3   invalide  invalide
```

Note that the index values along the left-hand side show the original row numbers of each entry. If you don't care about these numbers you can pass the `ignore_index=True` option to `.concat`.

Is this closer to what you wanted?

#### Original

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! I'm not sure if I completely understand your question. For example, in your sample code it does not appear that you use the loop variable `x` in each iteration. It may help to see an example `DataFrame` that has the same structure as the one you are working with.

My impression is that your question may be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842066/python-pandas-certain-columns-to-rows) which uses [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html).

Is your `DataFrame` structured like the following?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"A": list(range(1, 10)), "B": list(range(11, 20)), "C": range(21, 30)}
)
>>> df.head()

    A   B   C
0   1   11  21
1   2   12  22
2   3   13  23
3   4   14  24
4   5   15  25
5   6   16  26
6   7   17  27
7   8   18  28
8   9   19  29
```

If so, you can use `pd.melt` to restructure it to have two columns, a "column names" column and a "column values" column, as you describe in your question.

The command and output for the example `DataFrame` above would be:

```
>>> pd.melt(df, value_vars=['A', 'B', 'C'])

  variable  value
0   A   1
1   A   2
2   A   3
3   A   4
4   A   5
5   A   6
6   A   7
7   A   8
8   A   9
9   B   11
10  B   12
11  B   13
12  B   14
13  B   15
14  B   16
15  B   17
16  B   18
17  B   19
18  C   21
19  C   22
20  C   23
21  C   24
22  C   25
23  C   26
24  C   27
25  C   28
26  C   29
```

Is this similar to what you are asking? If not, could you provide an example of the `DataFrame` you are working with and an example of what you want the final result to look like? It could be a simplified or "mock" example.

Comment: Thanks Alex Kluber for your response, data with almost same with the above with boolen columns A_bol, B_bol, C_bol, I need a column that check if A_bol = true then return A value, if false check B_bol and so on

Comment: I have updated my answer @Abdelsabour. Does that answer your question?